What does “lady wife mistress of a household” mean?
I can’t tell if this is the lady of a house or a mistress, as in someone having an affair.
Phrase comes from https://www.ancestry.co.uk/name-origin?surname=tiplady

@Mari-LouA Link added

I think there should be commas in it - 'lady, wife [or] mistress of a household' .  The phrase means 'the lady of the house', but in the context of the derivation of the surname Tiplady they think 'lady' might imply a man's mistress.

Some websites have a different version: 23 and me punctuates it "lady, wife, mistress of a household". Both that and the OP's link reference Dictionary of American Family Names, 2nd edition, Oxford University Press, 2022, which should be your first port of call for accurate details and more information.

The problem here, as Stuart F suggested in a comment, is indeed punctuation. Ancestry.com cites the Dictionary of American Family Names (2nd edition), but if you track down what I believe is the original source the commas make it clear that there are multiple senses under consideration:

English (northern; especially Yorkshire): anecdotal nickname from Middle English tippe(n) ‘tip over, pull down’ + ladi(e) ‘lady, wife, mistress of a household’, perhaps denoting a promiscuous man or adulterer.

